# GWT compilation is skipped in maven when module packaging is pom

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am trying to reuse a assembled gwt compilation in another war. For this i am try to change the current maven module's packaging from `war` to `pom`. I then plan to use maven-assembly-plugin to zip up gwt's module js output and use that later on in another war module.

I tried changing the packaging tag from `<packaging>war</packaging>` to     `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in pom.xml from [Validation sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/pom.xml) . gwt-maven-plugin never enters into compilation. Instead, it skips compilation!!!!!

1. **`What is happening?`**
2. **`Is this expected?`**
3. **`Is there any workaround?`**

[image]

Comment: I dont understand why do you want to change from war to pom? You can produce a .zip after having a .war. I dont follow what you want to do in this second module

Comment: war to pom. Curiosity :) I spent a day before realizing gwt compilation was getting skipped.

Comment: I can make do with war rather than zip and war ( by extracting the contents when i need into second module from the war itself ).  Assume i want to have multi-module project set up of samples where i do not want to compile the sample always instead download the samples compiled js and push it into my Mega Sample aggregator project.

Comment: If I understand well, you are saying that you want to publish your example1.war in a maven-repo, then in another module (examples) you want to unpack the static stuff from all exampleX.war and create a new examples.war, right?

Comment: @Manolo yes. You can describe it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To join multiple gwt compiled modules into a single `.war` file, it is very easy with the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)

1. Package all your gwt examples as habitual (.war), and install them `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` if you have a private maven repo.
2. Create an empty maven module of type `war`, with no code but with the maven folder structure, you can put any additional stuff you need here like a global `src/main/webapp/index.html`.
3. Configure the new module to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` like shown below, and run `mvn package`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>my.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>example1</artifactId>
       <version>...</version>
       <type>war</type>
   </dependency>
   ...
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack-gwt-examples</id>
         <phase>prepare-package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <includeGroupIds>my.group</includeGroupIds>
           <includes>**/example1/**</includes>
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Finally and related with the gwt-maven-plugin, like with any other maven pluging, it would be enough to select an appropriate phase of the pom-packaging life cycle (package, install or deploy):

```
  ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  ...
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
        ...
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, gwt-maven-plugin specifically disallows compilation when packaging is pom, take a look to [line #269 of CompileMojo.java](https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/shell/CompileMojo.java#L269)

Comment: Thank you. This answer's my 3 point. I am still unclear on gwt-maven-plugin behavior of skipping compilation when maven module packaging is "pom".

Comment: what is your gwt-maven-plugin configuration?. which phase do you use to execute the gwt:compile goal?

Comment: If u note I just change the packaging type in validation sample pom.

Comment: sgwt-maven-plugin skip compilation when packaging is pom, so you should select a different packaging or open an issue to the project, updated my answer properly.

Comment: That sums it up for all three queries. I will go with the work around for now. Will report on the CompileMojo code later...

Comment: We can use Maven [**overlays**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) feature of war instead of **maven-dependency-plugin**. It will be more easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the reusable modules (that you mention as *samples* in the comments) as separate GWT projects with no EntryPoint. Package them as `jar` and add the following as [resources](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources):

1. the client side source code
2. other resource items that will be necessary for the final compilation (images, xml files, etc.)

Something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/services/**</include>
                <include>**/client/**</include>
                <include>**/public/**</include>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

That's it, you can reuse it in any other GWT project. When you will do so, you just have to add the dependency (to the reusable module) in the `pom.xml` and `import` in the `*.gwt.xml`.

As for Maven's behaviour, it seems correct. [`pom` packaging](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Default_Lifecycle_Bindings_-_Packaging_pom) is going through `package`, `install` and `deploy` phases and

> By default, the compile goal is configured to be executed during the ''prepare-package'' phase to run as late as possible.

You could change the phase in the plugin's execution, but I think it's risky because you can't know when exactly during the `package` phase will your code get compiled.

Comment: That would recompile gwt module again in every usage context even when there is no code change. I intend to avoid gwt recompilation.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for misunderstanding. I'll edit my answer accordingly.